# "Not configured to allow writing data" error in Sitecore CLI (Sitecore 10.0)

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

I am using Sitecore 10.0, running Sitecore CLI in a Windows PowerShell console. I have made sure I am in the root folder of my project. When I run the command `dotnet sitecore ser push` I get this error in the console:

```
Environment default is not configured to allow writing data. Use what-if, or set the environment to allow writes in the user.json file.
```

How do I get the push command to have permission to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually means that your **.\sitecore\user.json** file is not yet in your folder structure. I had this happen to me when I initially downloaded a project and tried to get things up and running from what is in source control. Typically, the user.json file is user-specific so is not in source control, therefore would be missing after your first download of a new project.

You can trigger the creation of the file by executing a fully-specified authentication with the `allow-write` parameter set to true. For example:

```
dotnet sitecore login -a https://my-id.sc.localhost -h https://my-cm.sc.localhost --allow-write true
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to alter the host names above to the ones that are applicable to your installation. The first host name is the IdentityServer instance, the second is the Content Management instance.

You can see more details in the official documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/log-in-to-a-sitecore-instance-with-sitecore-command-line-interface.html